# How to center a link in a <li> with its backgroundcolor?

Tags: html, css

In Mozilla the text lines up like this

```
 __________
|          | 
|   LINK   |
|__________|
```

But in Safari it looks like this

```
 __________
|   LINK   | 
|          |
|__________|
```

Code:

```
.nav ul{
    text-align: center;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

.nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20pt;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Neou-thin, "Courier New";
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 145px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated! I just want the text centered in the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line-height will only work if you specify a height like this:

```
.nav ul li a{
height:100px;
line-height: 100px;
}
```

No need for vertical-align.

Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `line-height` property:

```
.nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20pt;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Neou-thin, "Courier New";
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 145px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:50%;
}
```

Experiment with the value after `line-height` to get the text in the right place.

Comment: Thank you guys! Really neat tips. However, I noticed it was the font I was using that messed things up. I changed it and now it works as intended. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "new way" of aligning elements vertically to center, using [this approach](https://coderwall.com/p/oo2bqg).

All you need is to insert the `<i class="inliner"></i>` before the `<a>` tag, and include the following css:

```
.inliner {
    height: 100%;
}

.inliner,
.inliner + * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I made a short fiddle to illustrate how you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/scFkc/

Comment: Thank you guys! Really neat tips. However, I noticed it was the font I was using that messed things up. I changed it and now it works as intended. :)

Comment: @pepefatha Glad to help :) If this helped you solve your problem, please mark an answer to help others vertically align elements to center :)